# Installing mpm_worker for Apache and configuring pre_main_global.conf doesn't seem to work

Tags: apache

I just installed *mpm_worker* for Apache and added this to *pre_main_global.conf*:

```
<IfModule worker.c>
ServerLimit          40
StartServers          2
MaxClients          1000
MinSpareThreads      20
MaxSpareThreads      50
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

To test to see if this actually works, I changed the variable and restarted Apache.

```
<IfModule worker.c>
ServerLimit           1
StartServers          1
MaxClients            1
MinSpareThreads       1
MaxSpareThreads       1
ThreadsPerChild       1
MaxRequestsPerChild   1
</IfModule>
```

To my surprise my busy site still responds as normal. I tested this on multiple browsers and deleted all the cache. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of **./httpd -l**?

I think your answer is here:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mpm.html

> "MPMs must be chosen during configuration, and compiled into the
>   server. Compilers are capable of optimizing a lot of functions if
>   threads are used, but only if they know that threads are being used."

Comment: You can also use "apachectl -V" for a slightly more user friendly output. The line starting "Server MPM" will tell you if your server is using worker or not. Also enabling the server-info handler http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html will allow you to see the current running configuration.